# WCF over TLS under Mono

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, tcp

I am trying to get WCF communication to work over a TLS connection. I am using Mono 5.20.1.19 on Ubuntu 18.04, although I would hope that a solution would work on Windows too.

Consider a basic interface like this:

IExample.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Example
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IExample
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Greet();
    }
}
```

I have a server that sets up ServiceHost for an implementation of the interface:

Server.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace Example
{
    public class ExampleImpl : IExample
    {
        public string Greet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Greet() called");

            return "Hello!";
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ExampleImpl), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:5555"))){
                var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
                binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
                binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;

                host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
                    StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                    StoreName.My,
                    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                    "server");

                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IExample), binding, "Example");

                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("listening at :5555");
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end the program");

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `SecurityMode.Transport` is specified for the NetTcpBinding, and `TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate` for the client credential type. I also specify a certificate which I installed to the `My` certificate store, in addition to the private key for the certificate.

Now the client:

Client.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace Example
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

            var factory = new ChannelFactory<IExample>(binding, new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:5555/Example"));

            var obj = factory.CreateChannel();

            Console.WriteLine(obj.Greet());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in the client, the NetTcpBinding's security mode is set to `None`, and no client certificate is specified.

We can build the two programs:

```bash
$ csc Server.cs IExample.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.8.2.62916 (2ad4aabc)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
$ csc Client.cs IExample.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.8.2.62916 (2ad4aabc)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Now, if we run Server.exe, leave it open, and then in a different session run Client.exe, the server prints the message `Greet() called`, while the client prints `Hello!`.

My confusion is why the connection is successful. I would expect that since the server's binding is set to `Transport`, then it should require a TLS connection; however it does not seem that TLS is being used, as no client certificate is being specified.

How can I change the server portion of the code to require TLS connections?

Answer (score 0):

First, I could not reproduce your issue, the following error occurred when I call the service locally.
[image]
Then, NetTcpBinding can use windows credentials or certificates to ensure transport layer security. 
Please refer to the posts I have replied to before.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7b300a92-8533-4afe-9e8b-3f38138dd23b/ssltsl-with-nettcpbinding?forum=wcf